# CakePHP 2.0 Accessing model field values for view/controller comparisons - Only letting users edit/delete their own posted items

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1, cakephp-model

I am fairly new to CakePHP, I am trying to only allow those users who created an event to be able to edit or delete an event, so I am comparing the current user id, with the 'user_id' field of the event the current event (saved when a user creates an event). Any help would be appreciated thanks, my code(Andrew Perk) is as follows:

```
public function isAuthorized($user) {
        $this->loadModel('User');
        if ($user['role'] == 'admin') {
            return true;
        }
        if (in_array($this->action, array('edit', 'delete'))) {
            if ($user['id'] != $this->request->data['Event']['user_id']) { ///THIS IS THE LINE I FEEL IS WRONG - PLEASE ADVISE
                //echo debug($event['user_id']);
                //$this->Session->setFlash(__('You are not allowed to edit someones event'));
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: This question should give you the info you need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13259937/best-way-to-filter-access-to-controller-actions-according-to-a-specific-client-i/13260534#13260534 In your case, the user id of your event should be available in $this->request->data['Event']['user_id']

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways you can accomplish this. The one I have found that usually works best is to put a callback in the model that will set the user_id for the record you are trying to modify. Then it doesn't have to get all mixed up in controller everywhere you are trying to CRUD a record.

You can read more about limiting user data here: http://blogchuck.com/2010/06/limit-data-by-user-with-cakephp/

This will also apply to deleting data.

Hope it helps. Happy coding!